# Setting up laravel 5 on Centos server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, centos7

I am trying setup a Centos Server with LAMP installed in it.

I have a laravel project created successfully but still when i am opening a route (/) its showing **500 ERROR** i don't know where did the configuration goes wrong.

Here is how my htaccess file looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

And here is how my **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf** file looks like:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

#
# Relax access to content within /var/www.
#
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride none
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride none

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have installed all the required plugins as well.

I installed wordpress and it seems to be running smoothly. But i am not sure why its not working with this.

Here is my project URL http://104.199.222.145/demo2/ i just did a basic laravel installation.

I am thinking this as a more .htaccess problem somewhere. But not sure.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Did you set up the permissions to the laravel folders ?

```
sudo chmod 755 -R demo2
chmod -R o+w demo2/storage
```

Comment: I tried this, but didn't work. You can check. http://104.199.222.145/demo2/. I also make everything `AllowOverride none` to `AllowOverride All`

Comment: What changes do you make on /routes/web.php ?

Comment: i didn't make any changes, just added a new route as we always do with a callback function.

Answer (score 0):

What's the laravel version that you installed on your server?
And what's your server php version? If the requirements are not met laravel throws 500 errors.

Comment: I am using PHP 7 and larval 5.3 version i am trying to install. I tried with 5.2 as well. But didn't work in either cases.

Comment: In laravel you are talking about?

Comment: In laravel and on your server